# Using ave() with function which returns a vector

Tags: r

I am wondering what would be the best way to add, for example, columns of quantiles to the dataset. I was thinking to use ave() function for that, something like  `ave(iris$Sepal.Length, iris$Species, FUN=quantile)` - but in this case `ave()` merges values returned by `quantile()` (which in this case returns 5 values per subset) and cut them for the length of `iris`...

Thanks in advance for suggestions!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a lot of SO questions on this general topic, recommending various uses of `ave()`, `aggregate()`, `plyr()`, `reshape2::cast`, or `data.table` depending on personal preference, readability, compactness, flexibility, speed ...  Here's a simple solution with `aggregate()` that seems to do what you want:

```
(aa <- aggregate(Sepal.Length~Species,data=iris,quantile))

##      Species Sepal.Length.0% Sepal.Length.25% Sepal.Length.50% Sepal.Length.75%
## 1     setosa           4.300            4.800            5.000            5.200
## 2 versicolor           4.900            5.600            5.900            6.300
## 3  virginica           4.900            6.225            6.500            6.900
##   Sepal.Length.100%
## 1             5.800
## 2             7.000
## 3             7.900
```

**edit**: re-reading/based on comment, this is not what you want: you need the summarized values replicated for each row, not just once per group.

Perhaps

```
merge(iris,aa,by="Species")
```

although that gives a slightly weird data frame (the last "column" is actually a matrix).

It's a little bit magical, but

```
merge(iris,with(aa,data.frame(Species,Sepal.Length)))
```

is better -- it unpacks the weird data frame returned by `aggregate()` a bit more (the names are still a bit wonky).

Comment: Ben, thanks for rapid answer! I know about aggregate, but it returns a "summary" table without original values while I would like to keep the original table and only add the columns with quantiles (yes, there will be some redundancy in it).

Comment: variant with `merge` works perfectly (although initially I was trying to manage without it :]). But I should note that recast does not work correctly: if you look on first, say, 15 rows, you'll see that starting from row 11, quantiles values are taken from another subset.
So, I will use `merge` variant. Thanks again!

Comment: P.S. @Ben, could you give me a hint on where I can read more about this "weird" form returned by `aggregate()`? It's not the first time I meet it, so I would like to understand how this matrix-in-a-column happens and how to deal with it in general. I don't want to create separate question as it seems to be something very basic - I just don't know right keywords to find this topic...

Comment: It would actually make a great question if you can figure out a way to formulate it. I don't know where it's documented, except obliquely in `?data.frame`: `If a list or data frame or matrix is passed to ‘data.frame’ it is as if each component or column had been passed as a separate argument (except for matrices of class "model.matrix" and those protected by "I").`  It doesn't normally come up in user-generated data frames ...

Answer (score 3):

With the **data.table** package:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(iris)
dt[, paste0("q", 25*(0:4)) := as.list(quantile(Sepal.Length)), by="Species"]
```

Comment: there seems to be a typo (missing parentheses?) - last line gives me an error `Error in \`[.data.frame\`(dt, , \`:=\`(paste0("q", 25 * (0:4)), as.list(quantile(Sepal.Length))),  : 
  unused argument(s) (by = "Species")`

Comment: oups, my fault: error was caused by viewing the table in RStudio. Thanks for another solution!